# Eigenvectors with imaginary part

Tags: output-formatting, linear-algebra

I am working on the following:

```
m = MatrixForm[{{0.25, 0.15, 0.75}, {0.65, 0.7, 0.1}, {0.1, 0.15, 
        0.15}}]
r = Eigenvalues[{{0.25, 0.15, 0.75}, {0.65, 0.7, 0.1}, {0.1, 0.15, 
        0.15}}]
```

To which I get:

```
{1. + 0. I, 0.05 + 0.165831 I, 0.05 - 0.165831 I}
```

Corresponding Eigenvectors:

```
{{0.384178 + 0. I, 0.900418 + 0. I, 
  0.204095 + 0. I}, {0.707107 + 0. I, -0.648181 - 
   0.195434 I, -0.0589256 + 0.195434 I}, {0.707107 + 
   0. I, -0.648181 + 0.195434 I, -0.0589256 - 0.195434 I}}
```

Does Mathematica have a method to take said Eigenvectors and print out a nicer looking expression? The vectors in question arise from a general solution a discrete dynamical system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume by nicer looking you means something easy to read. Does this work?

```
m = {{0.25, 0.15, 0.75}, {0.65, 0.7, 0.1}, {0.1, 0.15, 0.15}};
TableForm[#2//Chop, TableHeadings -> {#1}] & @@ Eigensystem[m]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: +1 also do `Chop[#2]` in there to get rid of the `0. I` terms

Comment: Thank you, I was really after a combination of the two.